# Migrate a big database from Oracle 11g to 19c

Tags: oracle

I have a big and customized db on Oracle 11g with many store procedures, jobs, triggers, materialised views and data.
We need to migrate all data, structures, etc on Oracle 19c.
Do you know if there are incompatibilities or Oracle 19c is completely compatible with 11g syntax and structures?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look into this Oracle documentation about the upgrades, if you are using 11.2.0.4 then you  should be fine.

https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/twp-upgrade-oracle-database-19c.pdf

Comment: I especially recommend reading about the `COMPATIBLE` init param. Alternate link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/